# How typescript implements enumerations?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, enums

I was wondering about how typescript would compile an enumeration into a javascript code. So I implemented the following example:

```js
enum Contagens {
    UM,
    DOIS,
    TRES
}
```

And it was compiled into this:

```js
"use strict";
var Contagens;
(function (Contagens) {
    Contagens[Contagens["UM"] = 0] = "UM";
    Contagens[Contagens["DOIS"] = 1] = "DOIS";
    Contagens[Contagens["TRES"] = 2] = "TRES";
})(Contagens || (Contagens = {}));
```

But, I don't understand how it works... someone could explain this code to me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. The variable `var Contagens;` This creates the variable that will hold a reference to the enum.
2. The argument `Contagens || (Contagens = {})` the enum is used if it already exists, and will be set to an empty object, if it doesn't. This allows enums to be extended:

```
enum Contagens {
    UM,
    DOIS,
    TRES
}

enum Contagens {
    CATRE = 4
}
```

3. The function `function (Contagens) {` takes an argument `Contagens` that is the value from step #2. In this function it will create the entries on the enum object. It has the same name as the outer variable `Contagens`, so it shadows that variable. But it's the same value, so that doesn't matter much.
4. The assignment.

```
Contagens[Contagens["UM"] = 0] = "UM";
```

The result of an assignment is the value being assigned.* So `Contagens["UM"] = 0` does two things. It sets the key `"UM"` to the value `0`, and it returns `0`.

That returned `0` is used then in the a second assignment:

```
Contagens[0] = "UM";
```

Now the `"UM"` property has been assigned `0` and the `0` property has been assigned to `"UM"`. The enum now looks like this:

```
{ UM: 0, "0": "UM" }
```

This allows you to lookup a value in an enum by its name, or get its name from its value.

```
Contagens.UM // 0
Contagens[0] // "UM"
```

Which is handy!

---

* The result of an assignment when *delcaring* a variable is `undefined`, but assigning a property of an object or assigning to an existing variable will return the assigned value. JS is quirky like that.